# Timemachine Mac Mini with 2 Hard Drives

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, mac-mini, server.app

I have a mac mini server with 2 Hard Drives, one for the system and active files (Server HD) and one serving as an archive (Archive HD). Is it possible to use Time Machine to back up both disks and not just the Server HD?

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine ought, by default, to back up everything except locations it is specifically told **not** to, with the exception of itself & any NTFS volumes, which will be already in the exclusions list & greyed out.

System Prefs > Time Machine > Options…

[image]